# Show Dynamics CRM tabs in Javascript loop - performance

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a performance problem in *Dynamics CRM 2015*. I have to show all tabs, which are available on form. So my *Javascript* code look like this:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get().forEach(function (v, i) {
    var performance1 = performance.now();
    v.setVisible(true);
    var performance2 = performance.now();
    console.log(v.getName() + " show process took " + (performance2 - performance1) + " milliseconds.");
});
```

After run, script writes in console:

```
tab_10 show process took 4839.822311864544 milliseconds.
tab_13 show process took 5.218640743772994 milliseconds.
tab_14 show process took 4.996419017363223 milliseconds.
tab_7 show process took 3.8835254718323995 milliseconds.
tab_5 show process took 4.66844116813445 milliseconds. 
tab_17 show process took 4.570270927553793 milliseconds.
tab_20 show process took 3.5970468606719805 milliseconds.
tab_8 show process took 3.7335927407548297 milliseconds.
tab_16 show process took 3.5988317741357605 milliseconds.
tab_15 show process took 5.135642267643561 milliseconds.
tab_12 show process took 3.6483631227965816 milliseconds.
tab_19 show process took 6.199896921247273 milliseconds.
```

Why show of first element took more than 4 seconds (!!!), when next one took 2 - 5 ms???

Comment: Is this same if you shuffle the tabs? Controls set differs like subgrid, etc across tabs?

Comment: Yes. I've added before loop single line: `Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_test").setVisible(true);` and now execution my new line take 4 seconds, instead of first element of list.

Comment: probably DOM & scripts loading time of CRM page is showing as 4 secs. did you try ctrl+shift+q in IE to see the perf center (http://www.powerobjects.com/2014/10/07/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-performance-center-2/)

Comment: in perfomance center i can see, that my `onLoad` function with `setVisible` takes 4-5 seconds, and less than 1 second without `setVisible`. Form without `setVisible` calling is loaded much faster. Is it possible to improve performance of this?

Comment: instead if setVisible, `Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setDisplayState('collapsed');` or `'expanded'` will work for you?

Comment: What happens when you only set each tab's visibility to true when it is not visible? (So, first test if it is visible.)

Comment: Is the behavior consistent across different browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and different computers ? Client-side performance depends almost exclusively on the client (which browser it is, which OS, how many addons, how powerful is the client, how much load it has, etc. etc.)

Comment: @ArunVinoth `Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setDisplayState('expanded')‌` is faster, it takes 2.5 seconds. @Alex I've described this problem in IE, chrome is much faster (first show operation takes 600ms), but i've noticed, that situation in chrome is similar ( first operation takes 600ms, next one 1-3 ms)

Comment: Do you have an IFrame in that tab? If yes, then making it Visible will trigger the IFrame to load. Perhaps some other custom code on that page is hooked to the TabStateChange event?

Comment: @Eccountable It doesn't matter if i show tab or simple control. First showing operation always takes 3-5 seconds. I think that during first operation browser have to cache some scripts or DOM structure and it causes longer time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CRM Performance center](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmtools/archive/2017/02/01/display-performance-center-in-chrome) to capture metrics & study the component wise form load analytics.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("tabname").setVisible(true);
```

When executing the above statement `setVisible` for the first control, the product renders all the related DOM & scripts, hence the ~4 secs. And this reduces for the subsequent calls.

It depends on browser as well how it works.

Maybe instead of `setVisible`, you can use `setDisplayState` to bring down the figure somewhat less.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setDisplayState('collapsed')‌​;  
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setDisplayState('expanded')‌​;
```